# Initialize react state using function

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I am trying to bind dropdown in react for date selection, I have a year, month and day dropdown. I want to display the past 10 years from the current year.

I have tried setting state in the constructor and then also tried using componentDidMount but it's not working. It's not able to find state year options.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
class DatePicker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    yearOptions: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ yearOptions:this.getYearsOptions() });
  }

  getYearsOptions = () => {
    let years = [];
    var currentYear = moment().add(-10, 'year').year();
    for (let index = 10; index >= 0; index--) {
        var year = currentYear + index;
        years.push({ key: year, value: year.toString(), text: year });

    }
    return years;
  };

  render () {
    const {yearOptions } = this.state;    
    return (
            <Form.Select                                                 
                   compact                                                   
                   selection                                                     
                   placeholder='Year'                                                    
                   options={yearsOptions}                                                    
                   name="birthDateYear" />
            );
  }
}

export default DatePicker ;
```

Its not able to find state yearOptions

Comment: `yearsOptions` should be in format `{label: '2000', value: year}` most likely.

Comment: typo! options={yearOptions}  not yearsOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options={yearsOptions}
```

should be

```
options={yearOptions}
```

---

```
years.push({ key: year, value: year.toString(), text: year });
```

should be

```
years.push({ value: year, label: year.toString()});
```

Comment: but the others beat me to it, so don't accept mine;
both conditions need to be met in order for it to work

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
class DatePicker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    yearOptions: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ yearOptions: this.getYearsOptions() });
  }

  getYearsOptions = () => {
    let years = [];
    let currentYear = moment().add(-10, 'year').year();
    for (let index = 10; index >= 0; index--) {
      var year = currentYear + index;
      years.push({ label: year.toString(), value: year});
       // Clarity mentioned 
    }
    return years;
  };

  render() {
    const { yearOptions } = this.state;
    console.log("yearsOptions", yearOptions)
    return (
      <Form.Select
        compact
        selection
        placeholder='Year'
        options={yearOptions} //here spell mistake
        name="birthDateYear" />
    );
  }
}

export default DatePicker;
```

small spell  mistake  you have done

Comment: where do you see spell mistake, can you highlight it.

Comment: options={yearsOptions}    here

Comment: you can check the console you are getting the data, only the mistake was spell mistake, i have highlight the mistake

Answer (score 1):

you should set initial state in constructor.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
        class DatePicker extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){  
           super(props)
           this.state = {
              yearOptions: this.getYearsOptions()
           }
        }

        getYearsOptions = () => {
           let years = [];
           var currentYear = moment().add(-10, 'year').year();
           for (let index = 10; index >= 0; index--) {
                var year = currentYear + index;
                years.push({ key: year, value: year.toString(), text: year });
            }
            return years;
          };

          render () {
            const {yearOptions } = this.state;    
            return (
                    <Form.Select                                                 
                           compact                                                   
                           selection                                                     
                           placeholder='Year'                                                    
                           options={yearsOptions}                                                    
                           name="birthDateYear" />
                    );
          }
        }

        export default DatePicker ;
```